# Code not working when typing in UITextField the button not visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

This is my method for typing anything in textField, but the header button is not visible in header.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger finalLenght = textField.text.length - range.length + string.length;
    //SearchBtn.hidden = (finalLenght == 0);

    if (finalLenght==0) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }else{
        UIButton *SearchBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [SearchBtn setTitle:CustomLocalizedString(@"FIND CVS") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [SearchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionFindJobs:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        SearchBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
        SearchBtn.hidden = YES;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:SearchBtn];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When i am click UITextField and type anything in UITextField so this method is not calling so what is the reason i never understand ?

Comment: Did you set textField.delegate = self; ?

Comment: yes this is delegate problem i have solve it this problem friend

Answer (score 0):

How about changing this:

```
SearchBtn.hidden = YES;
```

to:

```
SearchBtn.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code

```
[SearchBtn setEnabled:YES];
```

or

```
[SearchBtn setEnabled:NO];
```